# How to configure multiple Gitlab omniauth providers of the same type?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, gitlab-omnibus

I am trying to self-host Gitlab. I cannot get it working by using two `omniauth_providers` of the same type. Am I missing a setting?

I've also tried using the `v1` endpoint for one of them, that doesn't work. Only 1 button shows up on the sign-in page.

```
    external_url 'secret'
    gitlab_rails['initial_root_password'] = '$INITIAL_GITLAB_PASSWORD'
    gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_user'] = ['azure_activedirectory_v2']
    gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
      {
        "name" => "azure_activedirectory_v2",
        "label"=> "Login using Tenant 1 Account",
        "args" => {
          "client_id" => "$SP_CLIENT_ID_1",
          "client_secret" => "$SP_CLIENT_SECRET_1",
          "tenant_id" => "$SP_TENANT_ID_1",
        }
      }
    ]
    gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
      {
        "name" => "azure_activedirectory_v2",
        "label"=> "Login using Tenant 2 Account",
        "args" => {
          "client_id" => "$SP_CLIENT_ID_2",
          "client_secret" => "$SP_CLIENT_SECRET_2",
          "tenant_id" => "$SP_TENANT_ID_2",
        }
      }
    ]
    gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = true
    gitlab_rails['omniauth_auto_link_ldap_user'] = true
    gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use strategy_class: 'OmniAuth::Strategies::OpenIDConnect' when you are using more than one omniauth provider for the same type. See example here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/5992